# SQL query to find maximum due date of payment

Tags: sql, database

I have a table consist of account Id, withdraw date, amount, due date, due date days passed.

[image]

A Single account ID can withdraw the amount n number of times till his limit reaches of withdraw the amount. now, I'm looking a SQL query to find the maximum number due date passed with all withdraws. In the attached table you can see there is a single Account ID did withdraw the amount three times and it could be more than three times. Now I should get the output that Max due days passed is 98 days. So the ask is first need to sort all the withdraw with due date passed and then should get the output of max due date passed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you described (and I understood) it, isn't it just a simple

```
select account_id, 
       max(due_date_days_passed)
from that_table
group by account_id
```

(with a possible `where` clause to filter desired `account_id`)?